# Why is my JQuery variable not sending to php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a variable which contains data, i'm then using a ajax function to send this variable data to this php file. I'm slightly unsure I can store this variable into php and echo it out. This is the code that I currently have...

```
var data = 1

// Sending this data via ajax to php file/ 
$.ajax({
    type:  'post',
    cache:  false ,
    url:  'function.php',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        alert ( data );
    }
 });
```

This is my php code

```
 $noteone = $_POST['data'];
 echo $noteone;
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`data` of your `ajax` call should be like below. Hope it will solve your problem.

```
data: { "data": data }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added this in { "data": data },

Comment: I'm still not getting any feedback to show confirmation ?

Comment: May be you should add `contentType: 'application/json'` to your `ajax`. @Ryan

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the data type:

```
var data = 1

// Sending this data via ajax to php file/ 
$.ajax({
    type:  'post',
    cache:  false ,
    url:  'function.php',
    data: { "data": data },
    dataType: "json",            // <---- THIS ONE
    success: function(data) {
        alert ( data );
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var data = 1

// Sending this data via ajax to php file/ 
$.ajax({
    type:  'post',
    cache:  false ,
    url:  'function.php',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert ( data );
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP requires data to be submitted in `key=value` format when building `$_POST`/`$_GET`. You didn't do that. You only submitted `value`, so PHP has no `key` to populate `$_POST` with. You need to have:

```
data: { "whatever_you_want": data }
```

which becomes

```
$_POST['whatever_you_want']
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain. I think its a problem with my php. I tried data: { "data2": data },  and on my php I put: $phone = $_POST['data2'];

echo $phone;   Still no result

Comment: then try `console.log(data)` in your js code and see what's in there.

Comment: Completely blank very strange